# how do I set up an iphone development certificate for ANOTHER mac

Tags: iphone, certificate

I went through the process of setting this up once, but now I need to make it so we can develop on two Macs with the one account. all walkthroughs tell me to

create a signing request or something on the new Mac through keychain access, which generates some private and public keys BS, and then it says to go to the developer portal and "add" a new certificate, except I CAN'T it looks like you can only have ONE!  I've tried just downloading the original certificate but that doesn't work, it doesn't come up under 'My certificates and it doesn't 'bind' to any of the keys...

I went through this process once before and all I could do was delete the original certificate and create a new one, but this no doubt stops the original Mac from working...

anybody know how it is done?

anybody know why apple put us through Such a PROCESS!? it is like the most difficult thing to do IN THE WORLD!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to export your developer certificate and private key from the Keychain on Mac A and then import those on Mac B. This is what I do. There is no need to create two separate certificates.

Comment: +a million points!

to clarify, go to the keychain assistant, click on certificates, select your Iphone Developer one, (and any others that might be there relating to dev), Go File export. 

then just copy the file onto the other mac and double click! done!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that a manual export/import in Keychain Access is indeed different from just downloading the cert from the dev portal. When you download it, it shows up under Certificates, when you import it, it shows up under My Certificates.